# Quick way to find eigenvalues of $\begin{bmatrix}3 & 5 & 3 \\ 1 & 7 & 3 \\ 1 & 2 & 8 \end{bmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is there a quick way to find the eigenvalues of the following matrix without resorting to finding the roots of the characteristic polynomial?

$$\begin{bmatrix}3 & 5 & 3 \\ 1 & 7 & 3 \\ 1 & 2 & 8 \end{bmatrix}$$

I don't see any patterns in this matrix that would allow us to determine the eigenvalues without forming the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: $11$ is an eigenvalue by inspection, since the rows all sum to $11$.

Comment: By guessing you can find $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ as an eigenvector.

Comment: By inspection, $2$ is also an eigenvector, just from looking at the first two rows; if you subtract $2$ from the diagonal, then the first two rows are the same.

Comment: Whereas if you subtract $5$ from the diagonal ...

Comment: @TheoBendit Why does this mean that 2 is an eigenvalue?

Comment: @Troposphere Then, the last two rows would be the same.

Comment: @user5965026 Because it means that the matrix minus twice the identity has linearly dependent rows, and thus is singular. This implies that it has a non-trivial vector in its nullspace, which will be an eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue $2$.

Answer (score 3):

Summarizing some comments (and adding one final ingredient), the three rows all sum to $11$, so $(1,1,1)^{\text{T}}$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $11$, and subtracting $2$ from each of the diagonal elements produces

$$\pmatrix{1&5&3\\1&5&3\\1&2&6}$$

which has determinant $0$ since the first two rows are identical, and thus $2$ is another eigenvalue.

Finally, the trace of the matrix, $3+7+8=18$, is the sum of the eigenvalues, so the third eigenvalue must be $18-11-2=5$.

Comment: I like your idea:  subtracting 5 off the diagonal (of the original matrix) makes the second and third rows agree

Comment: @WillJagy Not to split hairs, but this was [Troposphere's idea](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4220844/quick-way-to-find-eigenvalues-of-beginbmatrix3-5-3-1-7-3-1-2#comment8763645_4220844) originally.

Comment: @TheoBendit, Will may not have noticed Troposphere's comment. I actually didn't myself until after posting. My first thought on reading the question was that knowing the trace is $18$ should help, so when I saw saulspatz's comment I thought "one down, one to go," and then when I saw your comment I stopped paying close attention, except to see if anyone used the word "trace."

Comment: @BarryCipra Totally fair, but I thought, credit where credit's due. :-)

Comment: @TheoBendit, absolutely.